# Display SQLite table in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, database, sqlite, datatable

do any of you know how to create an excel file which can display a table from Sqlite using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas read_sql_query function with a query and your sqlite connection as arguments

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query (
    'SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE',
    conn
)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query, columns = ['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'])
df.to_excel("YOUR_TABLE.xlsx")
```

You will also need to install openpyxl with pip to run to_excel